# gcc: -DVAR=-linux not working as expected on linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have following C program:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEF0(v) #v
#define DEF(v) DEF0(v)

int main()
{
    printf("RUNNING... %s\n", DEF(VAR));
}
```

**Compilation**

`gcc -DVAR=-linux test.c`

**Running**

`./a.out`

**Gives**

`RUNNING... -1`

**Asm output**

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .section        .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
        .string "-1"
.LC1:
        .string "RUNNING... %s\n"
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB11:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    $.LC0, %esi
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     printf
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE11:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

`-linu` or `-linuxx` does not cause such problem, but `-linux/` does. Surrounding with quotes `-DVAR="-linux"` does not help.

Problem is also visible on gcc 6 and 7. On cygwin everythings works FINE.
I wonder if it is a bug or I do something wrong.

Comment: there's probably a conflict with the `linux` macro which expands.

Comment: What is the purpose of that macro? What is the actual problem it is supposed to solve? Perhaps you should define the macro-expansion to be a string to begin with?

Comment: I have `-linux` inside path, which I pass through `-D`, so I cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inhibit the definition of system- or gcc-specific macros by using `-undef`, when compiling your object file:

```
gcc -undef -c -DVAR=-linux test.c
gcc test.o -o test
```

Then your macros should work as you expect.
Note however, that you cannot use any of these predefined macros then, you should probably only use it on those object files you absolutely have to.

Comment: It works, thank you :) I have `-linux` inside path, which I pass through `-D`, so I cannot avoid it.